# What GUI tool can read maildir?

Tags: email

I can use mutt to read maildir on Mac, but is there any graphical tool available?

```
mutt -f /path/to/maildir
```

Since mutt can't render HTML emails, I will need something else.

Any ideas?

**EDIT for thunderbird**

I've changed mail store to maildir format,

[image]

And selected a local folder,

[image]

The UI become like this, unexpected ..

[image]

Comment: I assume that https://debian-administration.org/article/75/Reading_HTML_email_with_Mutt is not what you want?

Comment: @patrix nope ..

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird can use maildir. https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basics/Maildir-in-Thunderbird/ta-p/32138. Create a new account in thunderbird. Quit thunderbird. cd to the newly created maildir. rm -rf and then symlink to your existing maildir you used with mutt. Reopen thunderbird.

Comment: Looks good, where should I symlink the maildir to?

Comment: @daisy It looks like you are pointing to the original maildir from inside thunderbird. I was suggesting that you let thunderbird make a new maildir, then delete it. then symlink. rm -rf /path/to/thunderbirdmaildir ;; ln -s  /path/to/muttmaildir /path/tothunderbirdmaildir  ;; why not let thunderbird or Mail.app just redownload the messages from imap?

Comment: As of March 20,  2024, the above support.mozilla.org page is 404, Page Not Found.